# SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model + set the value of a multiple lookup field with Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I'm trying to update a list item with the SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model and Javascript.  The item I am trying to update has a Multiple Value Lookup field.  I can successfully set this field, but only with one value.  Does anyone know how to set it with multiple values?

```
var _newLookupField = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
    _newLookupField.set_lookupId(itemArray.toString()); //this works if array is only 1 item        

    currentItem.set_item('Lookup_x0020_Field', _newLookupField);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var lookupsIds = [1,2,4];
var lookups = [];
for (var ii in lookupsIds) {
    var lookupValue = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
    lookupValue.set_lookupId(lookupsIds[ii]);
    lookups.push(lookupValue);
}
currentItem.set_item('Lookup_x0020_Field', lookups);
currentItem.update();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a blog post that clearly explain  how to add a list item that contains metadata with lookup fields.

http://vangalvenkat.blogspot.com/2011/10/adding-new-document-item-whose-metadata.html