# Sharepoint 2013. Multivalue lookup field with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Is there a way to edit a multivalue lookup field using the JavaScript Client Object Model?
I need to remove one or more lookup values and, eventually, add one or more values.

I search everywhere, I read MSDN documentation, ..., I also take a look under my desk!

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Multiple-Column Lookup` value is represented as an array of [SP.FieldLookupValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246742%28v=office.15%29.aspx) objects.

### How to read multiple `Lookup` field value

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var listItem = list.getItemById(1);   
context.load(listItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(
   function() {
       var lookupVals = listItem.get_item(fieldName); //get multi lookup value (SP.FieldLookupValue[])
       for(var i = 0;i < lookupVals.length;i++) {
           console.log(lookupVals[i].get_lookupId()); //print Id
           console.log(lookupVals[i].get_lookupValue()); //print Value
       }
   },
   function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   }
);
```

### How to update multiple `Lookup` field value

For updating multiple Lookup value you need to specify value of type `SP.FieldLookupValue[]`. Note, `SP.FieldLookupValue` could be initialized by specifying `LookupId` only.

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var listItem = list.getItemById(1);   

var lookupVals = [];
//set 1st Lookup value
var lookupVal1 = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
lookupVal1.set_lookupId(1);
lookupVals.push(lookupVal1);
//set 2nd Lookup value
var lookupVal2 = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
lookupVal2.set_lookupId(2);
lookupVals.push(lookupVal2);

listItem.set_item(fieldName,lookupVals);
listItem.update();

context.executeQueryAsync(
   function() {
        console.log('Multi lookup field has been updated');
   },
   function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   }
);
```

Comment: Of course, I made a mistake: I press enter for a new line in the comment but in this way I posted an uncomplete comment... full message: Thank you very much. But I have already tried this code (I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043316/sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-set-the-value-of-a-multiple-lookup-field-w?rq=1 . It run without errors, but it doesn't update the item. I thought SharePoint 2010 differs from 2013. Have you tried (the code you posted) on Sharepoint 2013?

Comment: yep, tested it before posting the answer with SharePoint 2013 and it works for me. 
Btw, the link that you have provided describes the same way of updating of multiple lookup value, the only difference that in my case it is a complete code snippet

Comment: Yes, your code is better :-) . Anyway, the link is for SharePoint 2010. I thought SharePoint 2013 code was different.

Comment: Thanks, glad to hear that :) Regarding Lookup fields, i believe there is no difference between SharePoint 2010 & 2013 CSOM. But in case of Taxonomy fields, for example, there is a difference.

Comment: I understand my error. The method listItem.update() doesn't made an ajax request. To update the context is necessary to call context.executeQueryAsync().

Answer (score 0):

You can get lookup values via js this way:

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {

```
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                chartX.push(oListItem.get_item(xAxisName));


            }
    lookupValue1= chartX["0"].$1g_1;
    lookupValue2= chartX["1"].$1g_1;
```

Comment: don't do this , `$1g_1` is an _internal property_ which could be changed with a next version of SharePoint JavaScript library